# Which part of the PHB is free for public use?

Tags: dnd-5e, intellectual-property

I'm designing an iOS app could help us in game. The app including a "spell quick reference" section. Can I use the spell list in the PHB? In the future, I want to add more to it, like feats. Can I use them in my app?

Comment: Are you asking about developing an app to use privately for your own personal game after having already bought a copy of the PHB?  That is extremely safe from an intellectual property standpoint, and copyright protections are basically irrelevant there (and there is substantial case law to back that up).  That's completely different than building an app for public use, though.  Your title seems to lean towards sharing the app but your terse description seems the other way. Can you please clarify which it is?

Comment: I would suggest you download an existing app, there are plenty of good ones already. No need to build your own.

Answer (score 43):

None.

But you *can* use the content in the [SRD (Systems Reference Document)](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd), as long as you follow the terms of the OGL (Open Gaming License), which is included with it.

The SRD contains *all* the mechanical rules and *some* of the creative content from the PHB, MM, and DMG.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77811/discussion-on-answer-by-adeptus-which-part-of-the-phb-is-free-for-public-use).